# it is with great pleasure

Tags: prepositions

*Mr. President-elect:*

*it is with great pleasure to add my warmest congratulations on your election as the President of the United States of America.*

I would like to ask if a native speaker finds the formulation "it is with great pleasure to add…" OK? Is the preposition "with" necessary? – And what about the article? Does not by chance the indefinite one miss before "great pleasure"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's neither grammatical nor pleasant-sounding.

The stock phrase is "It is with great pleasure *that I verb* ...".

"It is with great pleasure that I announce the winners...", "It is with great pleasure that I accept this award...", etc.

Your expression would be better worded as

> It is with great pleasure *that I offer you* my warmest congratulations...

Or alternatively

> It *is a great pleasure* to add my congratulations...

Answer (score 2):

"It is with great pleasure that ..." is a standard idiomatic formality in English.   In general you will use this form without variation:

> **It is with great pleasure that** we announce the winner of the contest.
>
> **It is with great pleasure that** I introduce our new company president ...
>
> **It is with great pleasure that** I congratulate you on your victory.